# batch rename files that start with '-'?

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I usually get a bunch of files whose name start with a dash '-' . This is causing all sorts of problem when i do any kind of linux commands because anything after - is interpreted as a flag. 
What is the fastest way to rename these files without dash character in the front of the file. I can manually rename each file by adding a '--' in front of the file name.For eg: '-File1'  will be renamed as

```
mv -- -File1 File1
```

But this is not ideal when i have to rename 100's of files on the fly. Currently I have to export it out and use a windows program so I can batch rename them and then upload it back to a Linux box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the util-linux package (most do?):

```
rename - '' ./-*
```

[man rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to refer to such a file is `./-File1`. (You only have the problem if the file is in the current directory, anyway.) Maybe if you get used to that it's not so bad.

To bulk rename them, you could do something like:

```
for f in -*; do mv "./$f" "renamed$f"; done
```

or, as @shellter suggests in a comment, to reproduce the example in the OP:

```
for f in -*; do mv "./$f" "${f#-}"; done
```

Note: the above will only remove a single `-` from the name.

Comment: Given the example by O.P. the target for `mv` could be `"${f#-}"`. Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks . Both methods help me get around the problem. One question is what does "#-" do ? I googled around and can't find what it does. Is it some kind of regex that asks the value of variable f to delete the first character ?

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to do this in the shell, but if you're worried about special cases or if you would just rather use perl there's a couple ways to do it.  One is to use `File::Copy mv`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy qw(mv);

opendir(my $dir, ".") or die "Can't open $!";
foreach my $file (readdir($dir)) {
    my $new_name = $file =~ s/^-+//r;  #works if filename begins with multiple '-'s
    if ($new_name ne $file) {
        say "$file -> $new_name";
        mv $file, $new_name;
    }
}
```

or use the `rename` builtin, but this theoretically can not work for some system implementations:

```
rename $file, $new_name;  #instead of mv $file, $new_name;
```

In either case, if a file with the new name exists it will get silently overwritten with this code.  You might need some logic to take care of that:

```
# Stick inside the "if" clause above
if (-e $new_name) {
    say "$new_name already exists!"
    next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using find:

```
find -name '-*' -exec rename -- - '' {} \;
```